# Sharepoint 2007 Workflows

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have an initial workflow in Sharepoint Designer that triggers whenever an item is created and also whenever an item has changed in the 'Employee' list .

Within second workflow I am updating the 'Employee' list and the workflow above is triggered.

Is there any way I can check in the intial workflow if the item has been updated by a user or if it was updated by a workflow. In the case if the item was updated by a workflow I would not want to trgigger it.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a (hidden) field in the list, which value is updated by one of the workflows. You can then check in the other workflow if it has been set or not.

Make sure you reset the values in this column if the workflow runs a seconds time.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not have an additional site column that one of the conditions of the workflow is to set the column to 1. This could then be checked from the second workflow.